# How to find the variance of a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

> X has normal distribution with the expected value of 70 and variance of σ.
>
> It is known that $P(67.36\le X \le 72.64) = 0.34$
>
> find σ

So if I understand this right we know that $X$~$N(70, σ^2)$
I tried to find $ϕ(z)=0.34$ but in the table we can't find $0.34$ so we will search for $ϕ(-z)=0.66$ instead which gives us that $-z=0.4124$ -> $z=-0.4124$

so assuming I am right so far I now tried to break down the $P(67.36\le X \le 72.64)$ part
which should be equal to $ϕ(\frac{2.64}{σ})-ϕ(\frac{-2.64}{σ})=ϕ(-0.4124)$

This is where I got stuck because I don't know how to continue from here (not even sure what I am allowed to do on the function ϕ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have spotted, $67.36+2.64=70=72.64-2.64$ so you have symmetry about the known mean

So you could be look at $P(X \le 72.64) = 0.5+\frac{0.34}{2}$ and so $\Phi\left(\frac{2.64}{\sigma } \right)=0.67$ which you can use with your tables to give $\frac{2.64}{\sigma } \approx 0.44$ and so find $\sigma^2$

Comment: Thanks, I wonder was my way wrong or impossible? in your way I understood all except why $\Phi\left(\frac{2.64}{\sigma } \right)=0.67$ did you do $1-0.34=0.66$? and if you did it then shouldn't we say we have found $-z$ so in your example it would be $-0.44$ instead of $0.44$?

Comment: oh about the $\Phi\left(\frac{2.64}{\sigma } \right)=0.67$ part I understand you just did the calculation my bad. I just wonder if it wouldn't be that exact numbers (67.36 and 72.64) how would it be possible to solve(maybe it wouldn't)

Comment: Without the symmetry it would be rather harder, though not impossible.  Suppose the question had been $P(67\le X\le 72)=0.3$ with known mean of $70$.  You would then be trying to solve $\Phi\left(\frac{2}{\sigma } \right)  - \Phi\left(-\frac{3}{\sigma } \right) = 0.3$ and some effort involving trial and error might give $\sigma^2 \approx 41.84$